# Architecting Domain Layer and other modules with dependency injection in mind

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, object-oriented-design, dependency-injection, design

I am currently new to [Dependency Injection pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). I am influenced by [link by Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application/9503612#9503612).

**I have a confusion regarding whether an interface for an agent class of some agent module should be included in domain layer?** 
*by agent I mean a class / module that interacts with external wcf/ webservices.*

I have a [diagram](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3sGu5jelUWlUTRDZTdRbFdVeUE/edit?usp=sharing) that shows it. 
In short, is it Ok to have:

IProductAgent interface in Business layer where the actual implementation will be in an Agent Module.

The confusion arises by the fact that:  **Is calling a service even considered a business rule?**

Today a service fulfills a facility, tomorrow there might be some another means of catering this same facility. [Liskov's Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Apologies if I am mixing things here.

Comment: I don't see anything in your "diagram" link.

Comment: @RobertHarvey fixed the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the domain layer may have external dependencies where the dependencies are defined by interfaces. Taking this approach makes the domain layer ignorant of the actual implementation

Erik Evans who defined [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) does in fact use this approach in his [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321125215) to be able to load domain entities from a data source.